# First time doing NetLogo ABM - encountering with procedures

Tags: parallel-processing, simulation, netlogo, procedure, agent

I am modeling a social environment where individuals are choosing goals based on their self-efficacy levels.
These Self-efficacy values are then updated based on how they manage the goal. They are then allowed to switch goals if they did not succeed or lost courage to continue.

So far I have three problems.

1. I want personal se-values for each individual, so that once an individual is initialized and have gone through the process of choosing a goal, updating its efficacy and possibly selecting a new goal, then its values are no longer affected. I.e., the initialization of a new agent should not change these values, and a new agent should not inherit the values from it former agent. Does it seem like this is indeed what is happening?
2. I want the "go" procedure to keep running until it's >599. I have tried to implement this, but when I press <kbd>`GO`</kbd> it only does 1 tick at a time. This should be easy to implement, but none of my attempts have worked.
3. I want the default color to be 79 for each agent, and then it should deduct 1 for each time the agent "swaps" goals. 
   Right now it seems that current-color is the global starting point, and then it is decreasing gradually as all agents go through the process, thus inheriting the numbers from other agents influencing it.

The code :

```
globals [current-color]

breed [individuals individual]
breed [goals goal]

individuals-own [
    pa-se
    ea-se
    vl-se
    sp-se
    pa-se-initial
    ea-se-initial
    vl-se-initial
    sp-se-initial
    efficacy
    efficacy-initial
    chosen-goal
    new-goal
    ;; setting efficacy levels
]

goals-own [
    name
]
```

---

```
to setup
    clear-all
    set-default-shape turtles "circle"
    set current-color 79
    ;; creating the four goals i the space
    create-goals 4 [
        set color blue
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
        ;; I want to move the goals towards the center, so I make them face the center patch and move towards it a bit
        facexy 0 0
        forward 15
        set name ""
        set label-color white
        ask goal 0 [set name "GOAL 1"]
        ask goal 1 [set name "GOAL 2"]
        ask goal 2 [set name "GOAL 3"]
        ask goal 3 [set name "GOAL 4"]
        set label name
    ]
    reset-ticks
end
```

---

```
to go
    if ticks > 599 [stop]
    initialize-individual
    choose-goal
    layout
    tick
end
```

---

```
to initialize-individual
    create-individuals 1 [
        set color current-color
        ;; Assign variables randomly
        set pa-se random-float 1
        set ea-se random-float 1
        set vl-se random-float 1
        set sp-se random-float 1
        set chosen-goal ["GOAL 1"]
        ;;record the initial value of each component
        set pa-se-initial pa-se
        set ea-se-initial ea-se
        set vl-se-initial vl-se
        set sp-se-initial sp-se
        ;; the efficacy in each individual is the sum of the four components
        set efficacy ((pa-se + ea-se + vl-se + sp-se) / 4)
        set efficacy-initial efficacy
    ]
end
```

---

```
to choose-goal
    ;; set initial goal based on SE
    ask individuals [
        if (efficacy >= 0) and (efficacy <= 0.25) [
            set chosen-goal "GOAL 1"
            move-to goal 0
        ]   
        if (efficacy > 0.25) and (efficacy <= 0.5) [
            set chosen-goal "GOAL 2"
            move-to goal 1
        ]   
        if (efficacy > 0.5) and (efficacy <= 0.75) [
            set chosen-goal "GOAL 3"
            move-to goal 2
        ]  
        if (efficacy > 0.75) and (efficacy <= 1) [
            set chosen-goal "GOAL 4"
            move-to goal 3
        ]
        
        let goal-name chosen-goal 
        ;; update efficacy values 
        ask individuals [
            if chosen-goal != nobody [
                ;; Deduct from ea-se based on the selected goal and pa-se value
                if (chosen-goal = "GOAL 4") and (pa-se < 0.8) [
                    set ea-se (ea-se - (ea-se * (stringencyfactor / 100)))
                ]
                if (chosen-goal = "GOAL 3") and (pa-se < 0.6) [
                    set ea-se (ea-se - (ea-se * (stringencyfactor / 100)))
                ]
                if (chosen-goal ="GOAL 2") and (pa-se < 0.5) [
                    set ea-se (ea-se - (ea-se * (stringencyfactor / 100)))
                ]
                if ea-se < 0 [
                    set ea-se 0
                ]
            ]
        ]

        ;; set a new goal if conditions are met
        ask individuals [
            set new-goal chosen-goal
            if (chosen-goal =  "GOAL 1") and ((ea-se / (stringencyfactor / 100)) > 0.2) [
                set new-goal "GOAL 2"
                move-to one-of goals with [name = "GOAL 2"]
            ]
            if (chosen-goal = "GOAL 2") and ((ea-se / (stringencyfactor / 100)) > 0.2) [
                set new-goal "GOAL 3"
                move-to one-of goals with [name = "GOAL 3"]
            ]
            if (chosen-goal = "GOAL 3") and ((ea-se / (stringencyfactor / 100)) > 0.2) [
                set new-goal "GOAL 4"
                move-to one-of goals with [name = "GOAL 4"]
            ] 
            if new-goal != chosen-goal [
                set current-color current-color - 1
                set chosen-goal new-goal
                ;;to check final goal
            ]
        ]
    ]
end
```

---

```
to layout
    ;; the number 3 here is arbitrary; more repetitions slows down the
    ;; model, but too few gives poor layouts
    repeat 3 [
        ;; the more turtles we have to fit into the same amount of space,
        ;; the smaller the inputs to layout-spring we'll need to use
        let factor sqrt count turtles
        ;; numbers here are arbitrarily chosen for pleasing appearance
        layout-spring turtles links (1 / factor) (7 / factor) (1 / factor)
        display  ;; for smooth animation
    ]
    ;; don't bump the edges of the world
    let x-offset max [xcor] of turtles + min [xcor] of turtles
    let y-offset max [ycor] of turtles + min [ycor] of turtles
    ;; big jumps look funny, so only adjust a little each time
    set x-offset limit-magnitude x-offset 0.1
    set y-offset limit-magnitude y-offset 0.1
    ask goals [
        setxy (xcor - x-offset / 2) (ycor - y-offset / 2)
    ]
end
```

---

```
to-report limit-magnitude [number limit]
    if number > limit [
        report limit
    ]
    if number < (- limit) [
        report (- limit)
    ]
    report number
end
```

Any recommendations are welcomed as this is my very first time doing an ABM.

**Problem #1**
I have tried "checking" whether agents are indeed having their own personal values by inspecting the color changes. But then I realized that the problem was in the way the colors change, and not necessarily in this part (having individual SE values)

**Problem #2**
I have tried moving the statement to the bottom, I have tried making it an if else statement. Nothing has worked.

**Problem #3**
I have tried making current-color a turtle variable, but when I then set it in either the "to go" procedure or in the "initializing individual" procedure, it just set the color to 79 and it never changes from that.

Answer (score 2):

1. This seems to be fine from a cursory look at your code. A way in which I generally do quick checks is with `print` statements. If at tick 1 and at tick 100 turtle 0 has the same variables, you can be reasonable sure that nobody was tinkering with it. If turtle 0 and turtle 7 have the same variables at tick 100, you know something weird happened with your setup, etc. For a more rigorous search you could try creating a list of all the variables of all turtles at each tick, maybe outputting it to excel for easier analysis. But I think that's overkill for this situation.
2. Making sure that `go` keeps on running is something you do in the interface rather than in the code. When you create the button, you have to tick the "Forever" box [image]
3. With `current-color` being a global variable, any turtle can access it and any turtle can change it. In general I strongly advise against letting turtles directly change global variables, unless that is specifically the purpose of the variable. In this case, you can use `set color color - 1` instead, since `color` is a turtle variable that they can access and change without changing anything for the other turtles.
   You describe one of your attempts had current-color a turtle variable and then setting it during `go`. From that I assume that it is being reset to 79 at every `tick`, which means that even though it will decrease when a goal changes, it is then increased again.